# Using optim() function in r for estimating median direction

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the optim() function in R to estimate median direction of a distribution of points on a sphere, without success. Maybe the problem come from my data. Here is an example :

```
x=c(0.6896091, 0.6213466, 0.6841073, 0.6172717, 0.6539712, 0.6791404,
0.7002285, 0.6712104, 0.6561555, 0.7016914)
y=c(0.030166968, 0.006057147, 0.028140402, 0.028727403, 0.002019733,
0.036516142, 0.015386166, 0.064270094, 0.070949828, 0.059841455)
z=c(0.7235532, 0.7835125, 0.7288383, 0.7862254, 0.7565168, 0.7330995,
0.7137530, 0.7384754, 0.7512830, 0.7099635)

data1=data.frame(x,y,z)

fn <- function(par) {
   sum(acos(par[1]*data1[,1]+par[2]*data1[,2]+par[,3*data1[,3]]))
}

optim(c(mean(x),mean(y),mean(z)), fn)
```

"function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

In addition: Warning message:
In acos(par[1] * data1[, 1] + par[2] * data1[, 2] + par[3] * data1[,  :
  NaNs produced"

whereas if I just execute

```
sum(acos(par[1]*data1[,1]+par[2]*data1[,2]+par[3]*data1[,3]))
```

I have a value.

Comment: I get `Error in par[, 3 * data1[, 3]] : incorrect number of dimensions` instead.

Comment: I get results (although warnings) if I change `par[,3*data1[,3]]` to `par[3]*data1[,3]` in your code ...

Comment: ok thank you. I saw this error and even after correction, the error remained. I cleared objects from the workspace and it's ok now

Comment: voting to close as not reproducible ...

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant `par[3]*data1[,3]` instead of `par[,3*data1[,3]]`

```
> fn <- function(par, data1) {
    sum(acos(par[1]*data1[,1]+par[2]*data1[,2]+par[3]*data1[,3]))
  }
> 
> optim(par=c(mean(x),mean(y),mean(z)), fn=fn, data1=data1)
$par
[1] 0.67003813 0.04792312 0.74096364

$value
[1] 0.3578782

$counts
function gradient 
     448       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL

There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```